# Python printing Numpy array to external file, places one row over two

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, external

I am printing a Numpy array to an output file by the following process:

```
outFile = open("onlyAGBDegreesFileFromCCD.txt", "w")
print >> outFile, stars[cStarIndex, :]
print >> outFile, stars[mStarIndex, :]

outFile.close()
```

which gives an output file of the form

```
[[ 23.26971668  29.80491687  16.773       16.04        15.913        0.733
    0.127     ]
 [ 22.94437516  29.80841967  18.419       17.899       17.426        0.52
    0.473     ]
 [ 23.05349588  29.8120447   12.761       12.076       11.814        0.685
    0.262     ]
 [ 23.38478761  29.81421694  15.552       14.838       14.638        0.714
    0.2       ]
 [ 23.35962509  29.81423361  17.543       16.851       16.653        0.692
    0.198     ]
```

whereas I want it in the form

```
[[ 23.26971668  29.80491687  16.773       16.04        15.913        0.733       0.127     ]
 [ 22.94437516  29.80841967  18.419       17.899       17.426        0.52        0.473     ]
 [ 23.05349588  29.8120447   12.761       12.076       11.814        0.685       0.262     ]
 [ 23.38478761  29.81421694  15.552       14.838       14.638        0.714       0.2       ]
 [ 23.35962509  29.81423361  17.543       16.851       16.653        0.692       0.198     ]
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Don't use `print` but `numpy.savetxt()`, maybe with the tabulator character as delimiter. The string representation of numpy arrays may replace parts with ellipsis (…) and adds brackets.  It's hard to impossible to read in the data for further processing with Python or other tools.

Comment: @BlackJack gave this a try and it did the trick, thanks :)